# How can I generate click events outside the Electron window?

Tags: electron

I'm trying to generate click events outside Electron-generated window. I'm new to Electron. Can anyone suggest any way to solve the issue. I can very well create click events inside the window just not outside.

I tried `screen.getCursorScreenPoint()`.

Thanks.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your post needs improvement.